# TextWatcher not working on Fragment (no Error)

Tags: android, android-fragments, textwatcher

I have a fragment with a ListView and a EditText, I added a textWatcher to the edit text to do something after text changes but it doesn't work, nothing happens.

My code:

```
 public class crafts extends Fragment {
   EditText iSearch;
   View V;
   TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            Log.d("Enter AfterTextChanges","WORKS!");
            String text = iSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            filter(text);
        }
    };

 }

  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crafts, container, false);

        iSearch =(EditText)V.findViewById(R.id.iSearch);
        iSearch.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
        list=(ListView)V.findViewById(R.id.list);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crafts, container, false);

 }
```

I try to print on the Android Monitor when text changes to see if something happens with no result.

Comment: Why do you have to inflate layout twice just return `v` in `onCreateView`.

Comment: @Raghunandan is right, you have to return the view your were working with, not a brand new inflated view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your `onCreateView` to this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crafts, container, false);

    iSearch = (EditText) V.findViewById(R.id.iSearch);
    iSearch.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    list = (ListView) V.findViewById(R.id.list);

    return V;
}
```